# Adding different views to viewStack and memory management

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
- (void)loadQuiz:(NSInteger )quizNum {
    if([self quizViewController] != nil)
    {
        [self setQuizViewController:nil];
    }
    QuizViewController *quiz = [[QuizViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuizViewController" bundle:nil];
    [quiz setUp:quizNum];
    [self setQuizViewController:quiz];
    [quiz release];

    [[self view] addSubview:[[self quizViewController]view]];
    [self setSlide1:[[[self view] subviews] objectAtIndex:0]];
    [self setSlide2:[[[self view] subviews] objectAtIndex:1]];
    [[self slide1] setHidden:NO];
    [[self slide2] setHidden:YES];
    [self performTransition];
}
```

In this method I'm adding subviews to my containerView. Sometimes I add an image. Sometimes I add a quiz. In another function that fires at the end of the animation I always remove the subview at the bottom of the stack so I never have more than 2 subViews.

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag {
    [[self model] setTransitioning:NO];
    [[[[self view]subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

My question is do I have a memory leak building here?
This seems to run fine.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you've set the `quizViewController` to `retain` objects assigned to it. If you do, then you've got a leak. This part looks good:

```
QuizViewController *quiz = [[QuizViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuizViewController" bundle:nil];
[quiz setUp:quizNum];
[self setQuizViewController:quiz];
[quiz release];
```

But here,

```
if([self quizViewController] != nil)
{
    [self setQuizViewController:nil];
}
```

You're simply setting the quiz to `nil`. This means that the second time you load a quiz, the first one will get lost off in leak space. The thing to do here is either to release `quizViewController`, or, if you do need to hold multiple quizzes, go ahead and declare an `NSMutableArray` property to hold them all.

The easiest way to check for a memory leak is to go into Xcode and select "Run With Performance Tool >> Leaks" from the "Run" menu. You'll get a nice list of all leaked objects, with traces to where the leak occurred. Here's a [good tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks. actually [self quizViewController] is a retained property.

Comment: But according to docs if I use the setter method [self setQuizViewController] the hidden part of that setter is that it releases before it retains the new reference. Maybe I am misunderstanding. I will take your advice and run the Performance Tool. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, you might be right about that. The answer is the same, in any case - to check for leaks, go ahead and run that tool. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on that tool. It's awesome (especially because it says there's no leaks). Yes.

Comment: Oh man, if you're looking for a sweet tool, try the Clang static analyzer in xcode: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/featuredarticles/StaticAnalysis/index.html